# SQL Lite cannot insert values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

**UPDATED**

I am trying to create a DBHelper class and copy everything on my old code. However, I can't seem to insert into this. I don't know the reason why, I tried to re-watched the tutorial in database but I don't see any error on my code. Can you please check on this code?

`DBHelper.Java`

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBName.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblSample";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2= "Title";
public static final String COL_3 = "Content";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "(id integer primary key autoincrement, Title text, Content text) ");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertValue (String title, String cnt) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, cnt);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return result != -1;
    //note this code is returning false
}

public Cursor selectSample(){
    //I also tried to use this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null );
    return res;
    //this is returning 0 count 
}
```

`}`

this is my code on `MainActivity.java`

```
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    boolean hasError = mydb.insertValue("Title1", "content1");
    if(!hasError){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Error:",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Inserted:",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This code showing `Not Inserted:` meaning, I can't insert into db

Can you please tell me the reason or atleast tell me how to show the error message while inserting data. So that i can atleast aware of the error

Comment: Did you debug it step by step?

Comment: please post the error logs

Comment: I don't have error logs, as I am using my personal phone to test it

Comment: i updated my question. Sorry for confusion

Comment: try to reinstall your app

Comment: @ALTegani nope, this code is returing false `result != -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Reinstall your App again and always use [sqlitebrowser.](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to insure your data is inserted correctly...i suggest you to use [Room lib](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as its the new successor

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I am trying to learn ROOM also, its just, i am not in a good mood today.